# Mapview transition like Find My iPhone

Tags: ios, mkmapview, pushviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

Im a little bit curious : I wondered how did Apple made the transition from the home screen of the Find My iPhone app to the detail controller. I need to use this kind of transition for my app, but I'd like some insights before digging in.

When you move the view or select a device, it actually pushes a detail controller (without animation) but there is no transition on the mapView and no delay on the map tiles. My guess is that they should use a single instance of the MKMapView and move it along between the controllers, but maybe there is another way.

Any idea how would you do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to create a CustomnavigationController and add a mapView under the root controller. It would work pretty fine except that the mapView does not receive the drag events :-/ Maybe it's a good lead?

Comment: No, anyone? Thanks :-)